# FNF Compiling won't work [LINUX] - source/Alphabet.hx:17: characters 2-3 : Expected }

Tags: linux, compilation, haxe, haxeflixel

I'm trying to make an engine for FNF (More or less a modded version
of FNF) similar to others like *Kade Engine* and *Fusion*,
but it won't compile because of an error in **Alphabet.hx**.
The error is in **class Alphabet**

```
15 | class Alphabet extends FlxSpriteGroupless
16 | {
17 |    <set name="BUILD_DIR" value="export/32bit" if="32bit" />
...
24 | <!-- <define name="PRELOAD_ALL" /> -->
25 | }
```

`source/Alphabet.hx:17: characters 2-3 : Expected }`  Does anybody know how to fix this?
EDIT: Please note that I have changed `class Alphabet extends FlxSpriteGroupless />` to `class Alphabet extends FlxSpriteGroupless {`.

Comment: It looks like the build system wrote itself to the file when the intention was that the file be used as a template and processed by the build system into some generated values. Can you find files in your build system or FNF’s buildsystem which have things like `<set ` in them? Pretty sure that is not a feature of Haxe to do buildsystem-y inline XML stuff…

Comment: It could be helpful to provide the line 17 mentioned by the compiler. The mix of Haxe syntax and Xml nodes is very suspicious, these build instruction probably belong to the build file `Project.xml`.

Comment: @tokiop 1, 2, 3 were labeled improperly. Let me fix that sorry

Comment: The xml nodes seem to come from https://github.com/ninjamuffin99/Funkin/blob/master/Project.xml which is an xml file, they don't make sense in an .hx (Haxe) file, they are different languages. The Haxe compiler doesn't understand xml.

Comment: @tokiop could they have been mixed up during download, or was there just a mistake in the source code?

Comment: It is possible, maybe try to work from a clean base, the original FNF code doesn't have this mixed up : https://github.com/ninjamuffin99/Funkin/blob/master/source/Alphabet.hx

Comment: That worked, thanks